# Select a string to change it

Tags: objective-c, string, select

I would like to create a plug-in necessary for our hospital, but I have never coded in Objective-C. I have been looking at many examples but cannot see how to select a specific word into a file to change it.

I want to select the word `MRSC` that is written on a line beginning with `0008,0060` and change it to `MR` (to tell our server that this file was sent by a MRI machine, which is necessary to archive it). I know how I can change the word, using `NSMutableArray`, but I don't know how to select my `MRSC`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, assuming ARC or GC memory management:

```
NSString *inputLine = ... ; // the line you've read in

if ([inputLine hasPrefix:@"0008,0060") // is it a line needing changing?
{
   // replace MRSC with MR and store result in same variable
   inputLine = [inputLine stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"MRSC" withString:@"MR"];
}
```

You could also do it with mutable strings if you wish, it makes little difference in this case.